# JAXB Unmarshaling unsuccessful using jersey

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, jersey, jax-rs

I have the following class which represents a POJO object

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;


// Class to marshall and unmarshall the XML to POJO

 // This is a class for the request XML


@XmlRootElement
public class KeyProvision {

    private String Consumer ; 
    private String API ; 
    private String AllowedNames ; 


    public void setConsumer( String Consumer)
    {
        this.Consumer= Consumer;

    }


    public void setAPI( String API){

        this.API = API;

    }


    public void setAllowedNames(String AllowedStoes){

        this.AllowedNames = AllowedNames;

    }

    @XmlElement
    public String  getConsumer(){

        return Consumer;
    }

    @XmlElement
    public String getAPI(){

        return API;
    }

    @XmlElement
    public String getAllowedNames(){

        return AllowedNames;
    }

}
```

A function from my class to which requests are mapped

```
@POST
 @Path("/request")
 @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
 public Response getRequest(KeyProvision keyInfo){

    /* StringReader reader = new StringReader(keyInfo); // this code just leads to an execution failure for some reason 
     try{
         JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(KeyProvision.class);

         Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
         KeyProvision api = (KeyProvision) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(reader);
         System.out.println(api);

     }   catch(JAXBException e){
         e.printStackTrace();

     }
      */

     String result = "Track saved : " + keyInfo;
     return Response.status(201).entity(result).build() ;

  //   return "success" ;

 }
```

if I change

```
 public Response getRequest(KeyProvision keyInfo)
```

to

```
public Response getRequest(String keyInfo)
```

I can see that the request is accepted but not stored as a POJO object .

if I leave it as  `public Response getRequest(KeyProvision keyInfo)` , I get a 400 error with the following message `<u>The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect.</u>` in my REST client when I try making the request.

this is my request body:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<KeyProvision>
<Consumer> testConsumer </Consumer>
<API>posting</API>
<AllowedNames> google</AllowedNames>
</KeyProvision>
```

What am I missing here that is preventing a successfull Unmarshalling from XML to POJO

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By JAXB defaults naming rules it will expect the element names to start with lower case. You will need to specify the names on `@XmlRootElement` and `@XmlElement` to match your document.

```
@XmlRootElement(name="KeyProvision")
public class KeyProvision {
```

And

```
@XmlElement(name="Consumer")
public String  getConsumer(){
```

---

**JAXB Debugging Trick**

When unmarshal isn't working correctly try populating the object model and marshalling it out to see the expected document structure.

Comment: Thank you sir , this is very helpful, the case was the problem .